# How to display alert message for the invalid login credentials for the login form

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php include('includes/config.php');
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$empid=$_POST["empid"];
$pass=$_POST["password"];

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT employee_id, fname,lname,empid,password, 
status, role FROM employee where empid='$empid' and password='$pass'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if(is_array($row)) 
{

        session_start();
        $_SESSION["empid"]=$empid;
        $_SESSION["role"]=$row["role"];
        $_SESSION["eid"]=$row["empid"];        
        $_SESSION["status"]=$row['status'];
        $_SESSION["employee_id"]=$row['employee_id'];
        $_SESSION['uname']=$row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
        if($_SESSION["role"]=='admin' && $_SESSION["status"]>0){
            $_SESSION['alogin']=$_POST['empid'];
                header("Location:admin/home.php");          
        }
        elseif($_SESSION["role"]=='TL' && $_SESSION["status"]>0){
            $_SESSION['tlogin']=$_POST['empid'];
            header("Location:TL/home.php");
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['emplogin']=$_POST['empid'];
            header("Location:home.php");
        }


}
 else{
    echo "<script>alert('Invalid login details');</script>" // this is not working
     header("Location:index.php");
        }
   }
  ?>
```

I have created a login form with the employee id and password to login. incase of wrong credentials i want to show the alert message as Invalid login credentials in the code, but its not working. since script is included in between php code. Kindly help me how can i get alert error message.

Comment: You can't both display an alert *and* redirect in the same response. The typical thing is to go back to the form and show a simple error message in HTML, not a popup.

Comment: First of all, if the credentials are invalid, the query will fail and `$query` will be `false`. You need to catch that, not blindly pass `$row` to `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: kindly help me with some source code how can i show simple error message in html

Comment: _“I have created a login form”_ - oh, you shouldn’t have ... (because of course this suffers from the usual flaws such as SQL injection.)

Answer (score 2):

Echoing HTML *and* redirecting won't work. My suggestion would be to pass a parameter, like this:

```
header("Location:index.php?error=login");
```

You can read that in index.php and display an error accordingly:

```
$err = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'error');
if ($err === "login") echo "<script>alert('Invalid login!');</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the alert thing on index.php by adding a GET parameter when you redirect to it...

Like:

```
index.php?invalid_login=true
```

This line:

```
 header("Location:index.php");
```

Should be:

```
 header("Location:index.php?invalid_login=true");
```

And in index.php add the following code inside it.

```
if( isset( $_GET['invalid_login'] ) AND $_GET['invalid_login'] == 'true' ) {
     echo "<script>alert('Invalid login details');</script>";

}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of my answer.

Comment: Remove -- echo "<script>alert('Invalid login details');</script>" // this is not working -- in your current code as well as It will cause a header error.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `if(is_array($row))` with `if(mysqli_num_rows($row) > 0)`